# Python, argparse. What about -opt1 -part-of-opt1 <parameter>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

```
parser.add_argument('-i', required=True)  # One directory path
parser.add_argument('-d', required=True)  # Output database path
parser.add_argument('-t', required=True)  # DDL-script path
parser.add_argument('-c -i', required=True) # Another directory path
```

I run *.py* script like this:

```
python.exe s.py -c -i D:\Temp\dir1 -d D:\Temp\out.db -t D:\Temp\ddl.sql -i D:\Temp\dir2
```

and get error:

```
usage: s.py [-h] -i I -d D -t T -c -i C _I
s.py: error: argument -c -i: expected one argument
```

How can i use it without rename argument names??

Comment: A better approach: allow `-i` to accept multiple arguments.

Comment: Why are you trying to design your interface with this bizarre `-c -i` thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `sys.argv[1:]` list.  I expect it will be

```
['-c', '-i', 'D:\Temp\dir1', '-d', 'D:\Temp\out.db', '-t', 'D:\Temp\ddl.sql', '-i', 'D:\Temp\dir2']
```

Note that the '-c -i' are split.  Because abbreviations are allowed, `-c` is accepted as short for that '-c -i' flag.  But that string is followed by '-i' and 'D:...'.  That's 2 arguments, not just one.  Hence the error.

Yes you can quote the "-c -i" so the shell doesn't split it, but even that doesn't work cleanly.  I don't see any point to specifying a flag like that.  It doesn't build on the previously define '-i' Action.

```
In [113]: parser.parse_args(['-c -i', 'D:\Temp\dir1', '-d', 'D:\Temp\out.db', 
   '-t', 'D:\Temp\ddl.sql', '-i', 'D:\Temp\dir2'])
Out[113]: Namespace(d='D:\\Temp\\out.db', i='D:\\Temp\\dir2', 
   t='D:\\Temp\\ddl.sql', **{'c _i': 'D:\\Temp\\dir1'})
In [122]: getattr(Out[113],'c _i')
Out[122]: 'D:\\Temp\\dir1'
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on user2357112's comment, this "compound name" is not a thing. Off the top of my head I can't name a single flag of a single program that does this.

Even if you manage to implement this (nothing is impossible, although argparse will be of little help), this design decision would be highly eyebrow-raising to users of your program.